# Sfdx project with typescript build process

Tags: deployment

I have an sfdx project. Some components are using typescript and require compilation as part of the build process. Building these files in my project dirties the directory with these transient js files.

I would like to be able to build my project in a separate directory to decouple the build process's artifacts from my source.

I have checked out using Rsync to copy my directory into a build folder before compiling and pushing, but the output directory has a different number of files than the source, which is concerning.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?